# How can I make this query run faster in SQL?

Tags: sql

How can I make this query run faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT l.year,
              (select count(laws.id) from laws as laws WHERE laws.year = l.year  ) as count
      FROM laws as l
      ORDER BY l.year DESC
    ) s
WHERE count > 0
```

It runs about 23 seconds for 10000 records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`

```
select l.year, count(*)
from laws
group by l.year
order by l.year desc;
```

Note that the comparison `count > 0` is redundant.  This will only return years that have at least one match.

I am curious how you came up with your query, which is much more complex than a simple aggregation.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know either how I came up with this query :)